# What is the connection between the electroweak energy scale and the vacuum expectation value?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, standard-model, higgs, electroweak

I am quite confused about energy scale and  vacuum expectation value (VEV). For example, [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_scale) says 246Gev is VEV of Higgs field. Does it mean if we go to a higher energy scale (like 24600Gev) for a lower energy scale (like 0.0246Gev), we will not observe Higgs field as well as other electroweak process?

Comment: "Electroweak scale" [is a bit vague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electroweak_scale), as there are several important energy scales all in proportion to the Higgs VEV. At low energies, the weak interaction is short-ranged due to W/Z masses proportional to the VEV.

Answer (score 2):

You have $v\equiv 246$GeV, whence the Fermi constant $G_F=v^2/\sqrt 2$ controlling weak interactions with energies much below your conjectural *v/100*  is all these interactions "know" about the Standard Model. The masses of the W & Z vector bosons are about a third of *v* and their effect on the relevant interactions is indirect at these energies.

The mass of the Higgs boson  happens to be about half of *v*, by "accident", and it is hard to see any effects of it in your conjectural *v/100*  energies, beyond the theoretical explanation of all fermions masses; so it is a "pie in the sky" issue at these energies.

By contrast, at your higher conjectural energies of *100v*, you are well above threshold for production of W, Z, and the higgs, and, in fact, you would expect to start seeing "equivalence theorem" features of EW unification, as *v/E*  will then be a "small" number! A small perturbative correction to expected SM amplitudes "before breaking" and the inner workings of the SM.

Comment: Just an elaboration: at energies much below $v$ (e.g. $\sim v/100$), the heavy modes (higgs, W/Z, even the top, ..) are much suppressed. The way people talk about this is by integrating out these heavy modes to get an effective theory of the low-energy modes, for example it introduces four-fermi interactions (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_interaction) by integrating out W. Historically, this is what people saw first, (this effective interaction), before being able to probe higher energies and "seeing" the W-boson.